# CKEditor initialize and insert html

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Hello im working on some project and Im using CKEditor as content editor and to not lose website loading speed im initializing ckeditor only on textarea focus, but I have one problem, I made quotation function and I wanna it to initialize ckeditor if it's not already and then insert my desired quote.

For now code looks like this

```
var app = {
   initializeEditor: function() {
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
      return CKEDITOR.instances;
   },
   initializeEditorOnFocus: function() {
      // There goes code for focus
   },
   quote: function() {
      // Note here it's getting ckeditor object
      var ck = this.initializeEditor();

      // There is more code with quotation

      // Insert quote in editor
      ck.editor.insertHtml(quotation);
   }
};
```

When im clicking my desired quote to be inserted in editor it doesn't insert quote but only initialize ckeditor, any ideas how can I make this working?

Example how I need it to work: Press quote button -> initialize editor if its not already -> insert quote in editor

*Note: This isn't full code this is just example how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution `instanceReady` fixed it.

Comment: can you please describe more about this solution